# Calculate exact no of week for date range

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

A person  is engaged in different works in different time duration which will start from Monday and end on friday as follows.Monday to Friday will be considered as 1 week.Any overlapping weeks be considered as 1 week.
Below are the scenario

```
"AssignedEngagementdate":[
    {"Startdate":"01/03/2022","Enddate":"01/07/2022"},
    {"Startdate":"01/10/2022","Enddate":"01/14/2022"},
    {"Startdate":"01/10/2022","Enddate":"01/21/2022"},
    {"Startdate":"02/14/2022","Enddate":"02/18/2022"}
]
```

Here I need to find the no of weeks assigned by this person and it should be 4 since one week is from 10th Jan to 14 Feb is overlapping in 2 engagement.

How I can do this in C# using linq. I was trying to fetch min start date and max end date from list  and find the difference and converting in no of weeks but it has not given the actual result since date assigned is not consistent.

Comment: SO is not a coding service - please demonstrate your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to convert each date range into an enumerated week range, or at least a list of distinct dates (such as Sundays) corresponding to each week or partial week.  SelectMany() lets you gather them all together, after which a distinct count gives you an answer.

Try something like:

```
int numberOfWeeks = AssignedEngagementdate
    .SelectMany(a => {
        DateTime firstSunday = a.Startdate.AddDays(-(int)a.Startdate.DayOfWeek);
        DateTime lastSunday = a.Enddate.AddDays(-(int)a.Enddate.DayOfWeek); // May be same as firstSunday
        int weeks = (lastSunday - firstSunday).Days / 7 + 1;

        // Enumerate one Sunday per week
        return Enumerable.Range(0, weeks).Select(i => firstSunday.AddDays(7 * i));
    })
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```

You may still need to consider and test cases where assignments start or end on days other than Monday and Friday. The above should handle most such cases.

Comment: Extremely thanks to you..seems like it is working for me.Since startdate will be always Monday and enddate will be always Friday for mine case.
Can u please explain in details your logic .

Comment: @shashankshekhar - First note that I made a correction to the lastSunday calculation. There was a reference to Startdate.DayOfWeek that should have been Enddate.DayOfWeek. For any given date, the DayOfWeek returns an enumeration from Sunday (0) through Saturday (6). Subtracting that number of days from the original date yields the Sunday date for the week. For one-week engagements, both Sundays are the same, the difference in days is 0 and the calculated number of weeks is 1.  For multi-week assignments, the date difference is a multiple of 7. Dividing by 7 and adding 1 gives number of weeks.

Comment: (continued) For a given number of weeks N, the Enumerable.Range yields a sequence from 0 to (N-1). The calculation that follows calculates a range of N Sunday dates corresponding to the assignment, including any intermediate Sundays between the first and last weeks. Those dates are fed back to the SelectMany function, which gathers them all together. Distinct eliminates any duplicates resulting from overlapping assignments, and finally Count does just what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Without linq, you can try this Datetime extension :

```
public static int NumberOfWeeksBetween(this DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    TimeSpan span = end.Subtract(start);
    if (span.Days <= 7)
    {
        if (start.DayOfWeek > end.DayOfWeek) return 2;
        else return 1;
    }

    int days = span.Days - 7 + (int)start.DayOfWeek;
    int weekCount = 1;
    int dayCount = 0;

    for (weekCount = 1; dayCount < days; weekCount++) dayCount += 7;

    return weekCount;
}
```